# Average without calculate zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some fields in the table, need to average those fields.
Then I run this syntax, because I don't want to calculate 0 (zero) value.

```
SELECT myDate, AVG(CASE myField1 WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE myField1 END) AS avgmyField1 
FROM myTable WHERE myDate = '2014-06-01'
```

On my syntax, the average calculation means.. Make zero value to null.
My question is, How if all values are zero...?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you get NULL.

If you want zero instead, use COALESCE:

```
COALESCE( AVG(CASE myField1 WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE myField1 END) , 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Average will not use nullvalues to calculate an average value

IsNull or Coalesce can be used to change null values to different values.

This script will change 0 to null and take the average value:

```
SELECT IsNull(AVG(NullIf(val,0)), 0) 
FROM 
  (Values(5),(7),(0)) tbl(val)
```

Since 0 is excluded the result is 6

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
SELECT myDate, COALESCE(AVG(myField1), 0) AS avgmyField1 
FROM myTable WHERE myDate = '2014-06-01' and myField1 <> 0
```

Comment: QA does not want to calculate the values with 0, that doesn't mean that QA wants to exclude those rows